# Facebook Messenger Bot Post back not working

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api, facebook-messenger, messenger

I have integrated messenger bot and its working perfect.
But now i am using postback button as when i click on that postback button bot not giving any data on web-hoock my server.
i am using for postback button like this.

```
{
    "type":"postback",
    "title":"Start Chatting",
    "payload":"USER_DEFINED_PAYLOAD"
}
```

I tried setting permission in webhoock but its still not working.
[image]

Comment: any idea how to fix ??

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same problem,
Pressing the button facebook does nothing.
And it does not make any requests to the server, and there is no error.
The problem is the page access token.
If you got the token from oauth login check the permissions.

Answer (score 0):

The `Page Access Token` you are using probably needs to be updated in your webhook.

Go back to developer app dashboard. Select `Messenger` >> `Settings`.
Scroll down to the `"Token Generation"` section:
[image]

Select your page from the dropdown, and copy the new access token for use in your webhook.

I had the same issue and this worked for me after searching everywhere for an answer.

Answer (score 0):

In the **Messenger** -> **Settings** section of your dashboard, try setting the `messaging_postbacks` field of **Webhook field version controls** to the latest version (currently **v14.0**).

[image: dashboard screenshot]